# Why are my handles and live corner options hidden for objects drawn with the pen tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I was working on a project in Adobe Illustrator when I noticed that objects drawn with the pen tool didn't have the option to edit the handles or round corners (meaning when the anchor was direct selected I actually didn't see the circle to round corners or the handles). The entire time prior to this while working on this project I had no issues, and I tried creating a new a document to test if the issue continued and it didn't, it's only this one file. I'm fairly new to Adobe Illustrator so I think I might have accidentally turned off some setting or changed something without even realizing it.

Any kind of help would be great! Thank you.

EDIT: Show Corner Widget under the View menu is enabled already as well.

Comment: Are you using the direct selection tool (shortcut A)?

Comment: @AshleePalka Yes I am using the direct selection tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the **Corner Widget** in View menu.

Check the Preferences ˜second image˜.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Corner widget is enabled under the view menu already. Sorry I should have included that in the original post.

Comment: Or try Ctrl H. This will hide or show the anchors.